# Flask sub.domain.com overrides session on domain.com

Tags: session, nginx, flask, subdomain, uwsgi

I have two seperate server one for domain.com and another for sub.domain.com, and I store sessions using [flask-session](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) and following configuration:

```
SERVER_NAME = 'domain.com'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".domain.com"

# Flask-Session
SESSION_TYPE = 'redis'
SESSION_REDIS = Redis(host='192.168.10.10', port=6379, db=0)
```

further more I am using reverse proxy using nginx and:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

When I login on domain.com everything is ok but when I refresh sub.domain.com, user logs out on domain.com(sub.domain.com creates another session and overrides the one which is created by domain.com). Authentication is done by flask-login and it's on domain.com (sub.domain.com only should get them).

I don't know what's going wrong and I appreciate any help.

---

**Update:**

I tried to run flask without uwsgi and it works as it should, but when I uwsgi and nginx the problem persists. I think something is wrong with my uwsgi or nginx config.

```
# uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]
master = true
enable-threads = true
process   = 3
plugin    = python
socket = /tmp/name.sock
base = /var/www/app
chdir = %(base)
wsgi-file = %(base)/manage.py
callable = app


# nginx.conf
server {
    listen 8001;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/name.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: do both servers run the same code?

Comment: Yes, they are soft linked.

Comment: Recently I figured out that problem persists even using flask its own server on virtual machine(vagrant). While running the same code on my host machine with the same nginx reverse proxy config works just fine.

Comment: I'm thinking that in spite of using flask-session and redis, somehow flask is still using local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mistake I thought it has nothing to do with my reverse proxy or uwsgi. Actually it was problem with reverse proxy and I could solve my problem by adding following rules to nginx:

```
    proxy_cookie_domain media.$host $host;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect false;
```